# Preloader Hidding Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to add a preloader function to my page. It's done. but the preloader is fade out like the image below. 
[image]

Here is my Code..

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //Preloader
    $(window).load(function() {
    preloaderFadeOutTime = 5000;
    function hidePreloader() {
    var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
    preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
    }
    hidePreloader();
    });
    });
```

```css
.spinner-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.spinner.windcatcher {
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 46%;
  left: 48%;
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 4em;
  perspective: 50em;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
  animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}

.spinner.windcatcher .blade {
  height: 0.5em;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  -webkit-animation: windcatcherSpin 4s linear infinite, windcatcherBg 2s linear infinite;
  animation: windcatcherSpin 4s linear infinite, windcatcherBg 2s linear infinite;
}

.spinner.windcatcher .blade:nth-child(1) { -webkit-animation-delay: 0s; animation-delay: 0s; }
.spinner.windcatcher .blade:nth-child(2) { -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s; animation-delay: 0.25s; }
.spinner.windcatcher .blade:nth-child(3) { -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-delay: 0.5s; }
.spinner.windcatcher .blade:nth-child(4) { -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s; animation-delay: 0.75s; }
.spinner.windcatcher .blade:nth-child(5) { -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; animation-delay: 1s; }
.spinner.windcatcher .blade:nth-child(6) { -webkit-animation-delay: 1.25s; animation-delay: 1.25s; }
.spinner.windcatcher .blade:nth-child(7) { -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s; animation-delay: 1.5s; }
.spinner.windcatcher .blade:nth-child(8) { -webkit-animation-delay: 1.75s; animation-delay: 1.75s; }
```

```html
<div class="spinner-wrapper">  
  <div class="controls"></div>
  <div class="spinner windcatcher" id="windcatcher">
    <div class="blade"></div>
    <div class="blade"></div>
    <div class="blade"></div>
    <div class="blade"></div>
    <div class="blade"></div>
    <div class="blade"></div>
    <div class="blade"></div>
    <div class="blade"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above picture, Preloader is Fadeout from Right to left. But I need it should not be Fadeout from Right to left. It should fadeout from the current position. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you put your sample into [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: `.hide` - that's jQuery, and that's how it hides ... try [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) instead - that's jQuery also

Comment: @JaromandaX I am already tried that way. Same result getting

Comment: @Firanolfind Here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5owfu397/

Comment: Here's your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5owfu397/3/ using fadeOut, and added jQuery (because you didn't in the original), and a setTimeout instead of window.load because it wasn't triggering for me - but you can see, fadeOut **is** what you want like I said

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you Jaromansa X. Its Working.

Comment: Great, so what did you do wrong when you claimed `I am already tried that way. Same result getting`?

Comment: @JaromandaX It was my mistake. Actually in my code, it's  Hide instead of fadeOut. After that only I triend in My code. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.fadeOut` instead of `.hide` method.

[JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/5owfu397/2/)